# Problem with plotting a function

Tags: plotting

For some reason the result of `Plot` of the following function:

```
Plot[-2 ln[{Cosh[1/2 (-(1/2) + x) 2] Sech[2/4]}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

is 
[image]

How can I get the graph of this function?

Comment: First step when `Plot` isn't doing what you expect: try evaluating it at a point, say `x = 0.5` and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: It should be [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html), not `ln`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Plot[-2 Log[10,{Cosh[1/2 (-(1/2) + x) 2] Sech[2/4]}], {x, 0, 1}] (*Log_10*)

Plot[-2 Log[{Cosh[1/2 (-(1/2) + x) 2] Sech[2/4]}], {x, 0, 1}] (*Log_e or ln*)

Plot[-2 Log[A, {Cosh[1/2 (-(1/2) + x) 2] Sech[2/4]}], {x, 0, 1}] (*Log_A*)
```

A can be any number.

Comment: `Log[10, x] === Log10[x]`